# Php - parsing url to friendly (Using regexp)

Tags: php, regex, friendly-url

Using regex I need convert this `string` url.

```
<a class="navPages" href="?mode=author&amp;id=9&amp;word=friend&fn=%d">%s</a>
```

To get a output format like this:

```
<a class="navPages" href="author/9/friend/page/%d>%s</a>
```

Or get result:

```
0:autor
1:9
2:friend
3:%d
```

How should I write the regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all between (`&` or `?`) and `=` with `/`:

```
$link = preg_replace("/[&?][^=]*=/", "/", $link);
```

Result:
    `author/9/friend/%d`

To get the parts in array, use the same regexp with `preg_split`:

```
$parts = preg_split("/[&?][^=]*=/", $link);
```

Note that first element will be empty with this approach -- result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> ""
  [1]=> "author"
  [2]=> "9"
  [3]=> "friend"
  [4]=> "%d"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$txt = '<a class="navPages" href="?mode=author&amp;id=9&amp;word=friend&fn=%d">%s</a>';
preg_match('/^<a.*?href=(["\'])(.*?)\1.*$/', $txt, $patterns);

$data = explode('=',$patterns[2]);
$my_array=array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $test[] = explode('&', $value);
    $my_array[]=$test[$key][0];
    unset($my_array[0]);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [1] => author
    [2] => 9
    [3] => friend
    [4] => %d
)
```

Then use `implode` to get your href.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution with 2 expressions (one to get the URL, one to split the link):

```
$link = '<a class="navPages" href="?mode=author&id=9&word=friend&fn=%d">%s</a>';

// extract the URL
preg_match('/href="([^"s]+)"/', $link, $link_match);
$url = $link_match[1];

// build the new URL and HTML link
preg_match_all('/([^\s&?=]+)=?([^\s&?=]+)?/', $url, $url_match);
$new_url = '';
foreach ($url_match[2] as $value)
    $new_url .= $value . '/';
$new_url = substr($new_url, 0, -1);
$new_link = '<a class="navPages" href="' . $new_url . '>%s</a>';

echo $new_link; // Output: <a class="navPages" href="author/9/friend/%d>%s</a>
```